# wxwidgets - wxChoice - passing what user have chosen

Tags: c++, frame, wxwidgets

My main window is called MyFrame, and there I have mathod

```
void MyPanel::OnNew(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
AddDialog *adddialog = new AddDialog(wxT("Add new speaker"));
adddialog->Show(true);
}
```

AddDialog.cpp:

Constructor:

```
   { 
   //...
  wxChoice* choice1 = new wxChoice(panel, 6, wxPoint(200,30), wxDefaultSize, strings_colors);
   // ...
  }
```

Method:

```
   void AddDialog::OnOk(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
  {
    Close(true);
   }
```

And question is how I get what user have choosen in wxChoice? And how I can pass it to main window (called MyPanel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GetSelection()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_choice.html#af13b41f102b0a819aead40919c5f4944) to get the currently selected item.

Comment: where should I use it? in AddDialog:OnOk? or in constructor?

Comment: Adding: "choice1 -> GetSelection();" in OnOk method crashes my app.